# Very cryptic error, possibly related to an unstable keyboard

Tags: laptop, boot, keyboard

HP Pavilion dv7, with one of the latest Intel Processors

Recently, near an issue where keyboard key 'N', has very erratic behavior, it either is hard to be pressed or it repeats itself like kept being pressed and rarely works correctly..

..the notebook may not boot after a proper shutdown and the caps lock key is kept blinking slowly, f11 & f12 are kept on and there's a constant beeping noise with no pattern, just a repeated beeping with frequent stops (HP reports the latest laptops mainly report blinking of LEDs, not beeps).

At first I thought it was a dead CPU since that's the hint I got from a webpage of HP about blinking Caps Lock. It also was a good idea because I was playing a game today.

But then something weird happens. If I press the keyboard keys to "accidentally" put them in proper position that does not produce this weird "N" key behavior (supposedly), the computer boots.

Also, what is extremely important, the computer is perfectly stable apart from  that. The notebook plays games for hours stably, it never shuts down on its own. The disk never has bad sectors. It's perfectly stable. Only if you're going to REBOOT it (or come from hibernation or shutdown, etc.), it may create this behavior, plus it has the "N" key problem, which I believe creates a confusion of "there is no keyboard" at start up or similar.

Thing is, while I do have warranty, I do not want to part with it for 10 days. Also, I suppose I will void it if I try to replace the keyboard myself (I can do it easily, I've done it before in old laptops, but this has warranty).

I'd like to ask superuser.com of any thoughts, if it reminds you of anything and if you think you have other solutions. Also remember the PC is perfectly stable in CPU and RAM and Disk even under very heavy conditions (e.g. games). It only has bizarre behavior when it tries to reboot, plus the keyboard key "N" has very unstable behavior (repeats, doesn't work, then repeats again etc.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a keyboard. I replaced it with a compatible one (not even one for the exact same model, for an earlier model).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure HP class the keyboard as a self replacable part. If the troubleshooting determines it is faulty they will send you one out and you'll fix it yourself. Thats what has always happened with us.

Comment: No.  The keyboard is not an "end-user replaceable part" as listed on page 10 (PDF page 18) of the [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02842278.pdf).  I had to send in my Pavilion dv6z-3000 for keyboard replacement when it started acting up on me.

Comment: oh, sh.. I don't want to part with it for 10+ days just for that. I reserve such horrible waits for total failures. hrm...... I hope there are other solutions, non intrusive. (a USB keyboard may work but may still produce those boot up issues) [since then old one would be connected]n.

Comment: By the way, the procedure doesn't look very intrusive. The main complex part is that it appears to need the removal of the dvd drive first. I wonder if it would be clear to do it "end-user" like.

Comment: I guess I'll make a specific question for it because it becomes very specific.

Comment: @dragonlord - Thans for the carification, we deal with Probooks and they are self replacable. **Leladax Could be worth asking support if they'd just send out the keyboard if you were happy to replace it yourself