# The keys on my laptop are not working properly

Tags: laptop, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

When I hit a key in the middle row 3 letters come on to the screen at the same time for example whgen I hit the <kbd>F</kbd> key the letters RF4 come up and the same for all the keys in the middle row, I have tried the <kbd>num lock</kbd> and <kbd>caps lock</kbd> keys but nothing happened I have also taken the battery out of my laptop and replaced it but still no change, this is urgent as I need my laptop for my business and I'm unable to use it at the moment.

Comment: Laptop keyboards are cheap; order a new one.

Comment: Have you recently spilt anything on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bad connection, or more likely, something got stuck inside of it (maybe something sticky, like sugared soda?) and is causing the issue you are having now.

If you are comfortable with doing hardware repair, I would recommend disassembling your laptop to the point that you can remove the ribbon cable connecting the keyboard to the main board, and reseat it.  Baring that, I would recommend purchasing and installing a replacement keyboard, or taking it to a qualified service technician in your area and having them replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If this is urgent, don't waste your time waiting for the best answer here.

Try these things;

1. Use canned air to blow any debris from under the keys. I have seen pieces of food cause similar issues.
2. Plug a standard keyboard into the PS2 or USB slot to get you by until you can replace the keyboard.
3. Take it to a technician who can troubleshoot the problem and repair it if needed.