# laptop keyboard backslash key stuck?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My laptop keyboard backslash key seems to have got stuck. If i open notepad it continuously starts writing. It stops for a while and starts again. But if i try to press the back slash key it does not show. when restarted it gave a beep sound. And now it has stopped.

Comment: Googling for "keyboard key stuck" will get you lot of helpful suggestions, e.g. this thread: http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-95/keyboard-key-stuck-darn-thing/57524.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)