# Numpad gone haywire

Tags: keyboard, numlock, numpad

There is an issue with the numpad on my Toshiba Satellite P875. Some of the number keys toggles the numlock function, and none of the number keys function as they should. Holding down a number key will repeat the number, but I cannot enter any single numbers. The numpad is not controlling the curser. I am running Windows 7 64-Bit. What can I do?

Comment: [Keyboard matrix circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit) damage? http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it

Comment: More likely, it's just dirty. Clean it. Or just use the numbers in the main keyboard area.