# Keyboard issue and HP Help and Support Pop-up issue

Tags: keyboard, virus, hp-pavilion

Last night my HP Pavilion started acting abnormally.

My keyboard began to malfunction; every button I pressed acted as a shortcut for things on my computer (i.e. <kbd>D</kbd> took me back to desktop, <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> caused the whole screen to freeze, <kbd>B</kbd> took me to browser, <kbd>L</kbd> took me back to the main log in screen, etc.) Whether I was on the internet, Notes, or Word, it did not matter where on my computer I was typing, the keyboard continued to act this way.

After a quick search on how to fix it, I restarted my computer as everyone suggested. Once my computer was back on, the keyboard functioned normally for about 5 seconds before it began to act out of order again. And then the HP Help and Support window started to pop up repeatedly.

I ran some virus scans like Avast and Malwarebytes in fear that I had a virus on my computer. Avast came up clean but Malwarebytes found some infected files. Once I cleared those up and restarted my computer, I thought I was in the safe. But, once again, the keyboard began to malfunction and HP Help began to pop up.

I continued to research for the issue and updated BIOS, ran more virus scans, and even attempted to restart my computer from an earlier date using the BIOS menu when booting up (I thought that the Windows Update my computer had just had the day before might have thrown the system out of whack -- it's happened before). Unfortunately, the restart failed every time.

In frustration, I turned my computer off for the night in hopes that it would be fine in the morning... Wishful thinking. It's still acting up. Someone suggested I Factory Reset my computer to see if it would resolve the issues. I backed up my files and gave it shot but it's continuing to act up with the keyboard and HP Help window.

The rest of my computer is fine -- I have no other issues except for these, but unfortunately both of these issues prevent me from using my computer. The strange thing is, they started out of nowhere. I have not downloaded anything, visited any suspicious sites nor have I have experienced any issues before last night. I was using it all day previously for school and it worked fine. The only thing I can think of that would have caused any problems was the new update from Windows my computer had two days ago.

I am at a loss as to what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try it in Safe Mode. Still doing it? If yes, then it's not software -- try a new keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard yet? If if your computer _was_ infected with malware, there is no guarantee that the malware is what caused the issue. It could just be a coincidence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)