# Windows 8 desktop constantly pressing “\” key

Tags: windows-8

I have no idea where to ask or to turn. But this is a doozie. :)

One of my computers has Windows 8. Recently, the person using it complained that wherever she would click in a field or place that text could be entered, the \ key would just start filling in. It's not just on a browser, it's also on the startup "enter your password" area and any other place you can enter text. Like that key on the keyboard was stuck being pressed down. Here's what we tried so far:

- Swapping the keyboard. It was a no go. We eventually tried it with no
  keyboard from the start and it still does that, so it's not a
  keyboard issue
- Ran a quick scan and a full system scan from Norton 360. Both scans
  showed nothing at all (no threats, viruses, etc)

I'm fairly confident in Norton's abilities. So, what would be causing this? For reference, there is no touchscreen either.

Comment: Are there any other peripherals? Is any macro software installed (such as VirtualHotKey)? Is it a touch screen? BTW, be care with the 'in or office' part of this question. According to the FAQ, we aren't supposed to provide help for corp IT.

Comment: Try using Sysinternals processmonitor & watch what is happening

Comment: possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Comment: Does it do it when Windows is started in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

*red cheeks* *embarrasing*

So, the answer was....

The person had a wireless mouse / keyboard set. We replaced her keyboard with an ergonomic one. We chucked the old one in a cabinet, and forgot to turn it off. There was something on top of it, that was pressing the \ key!!

OMG hahah