# Keyboard thinks that i press f6 when pressing l

Tags: windows, keyboard

Since 2 days i have a weird issue on my hp zbook 15. When i press the l button  my laptop thinks that i also pressed the f6 key.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Clean your keyboard and check...... or else need to check the hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Comment: @Burgi no it's not a duplicate of that.. The one here says that when he presses one key it effectively presses another. Whereas the one you link to describes an unpredictable situation

Comment: @barlop I guarantee that the user has something trapped under the keys. Possibly a paperclip or staple that is shorting out the membrane. It is four years ago now and there hasn't been any activity. Let the question get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in addition to some other keys acting up.  It got much better after I vacuumed the keyboard.  They occasionally still stick but vacuuming made it WAY less frequent.  Hopefully it will go away more after I vacuum more.