# Laptop keyboard malfunctions

Tags: keyboard, keystrokes

The keyboard suddenly started acting weird.  When I click the "k" key, the system thinks I clicked the right control key, and the fn key now acts like the "less than" key. All other keys are working fine.

I have tried all solutions on the net like fn and Windows keys, quick access, restart and shutdown, but nothing worked. I'm running Windows 10.

Any solutions?

Comment: First try an external (USB) keyboard to see if the issue is software (e.g. key remapping) or hardware. If the external board works, then you know the internal keyboard is the likely culprit and should be fixed or replaced. Otherwise, look to key remapping.

Comment: Is there something stuck under the keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](http://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to be the cleaning foam i used to clean the laptop caused this problem .

so i used a hair dryer for 10 minutes and left the laptop for a night .

the next day problem solved .