# 1 2 3 4 7 8 9 p and backspace not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, asus-laptop

I have an Asus x55c with a very problematic keyboard.

So basically I have a Windows 10 and I can't make my keyboard work with the following keys: 1 2 3 4 7 8 9 p and backspace

What I did.

1. I uninstalled the driver from Device Manager and then restart.
2. I checked the cables.
3. I tried safe mode.
4. I tried an older version of the same driver.

Update:

- These keys work in BIOS
- They worked in Windows 7 Safe Mode
- They don't work in Windows 7, Windows 10 or Windows 10 Safe Mode

Comment: Maybe the keyboard is broken or something changed your keyboard layout.

Comment: I forgot to say that windows 7 safe mode made my keyboard work but I fully uninstalled windows 7 for more reasons and I am now on windows 10

Comment: So it didn't work on Windows 7 either?

Comment: So does it work in Safe Mode on Windows 10?  If you no longer have Windows 7 installed, it working when you had Windows 7, doesn't necessarily rule out a hardware problem.

Comment: @Ramhound So: Windows 10 (fail), Windows 10 Safe Mode (Fail), Windows 7 (Fail), Windows 7 safe mode (Good)

Comment: Do the keys fail to work at all or do other things happen (typing other characters or activating various functions) ?

Comment: Many sites report problems with usual driver. You may try to install the last version (from the [Asus page](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/117/0/6/uMukvgmJcudOMl9w/45/) or from other sources on internet: e.g.  [this page](http://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/)). It is reported also that installing drivers for the touchpad there can be fixed other problem with keyboard. From the Ausus site `ATKPackage includes ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities.
To avoid displaying OSD abnormally due to compatibility issue...please update ATKPackage to v1.0.0038 or above.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many reports of keyboard problems with Asus laptops after upgrade
to Windows 10. Below are some procedures that might help :

1. **Bad keyboard driver**
   It is possible that Windows 10 has kept your old keyboard driver.
   To force Windows to use its newest driver : Start the Device Manager,
   open Keyboards, locate and right-click your device and choose Uninstall,
   then finally reboot using the mouse. (*Seems that you have done this one.*)
   Some users also report a conflict with the Synaptics driver, so if you have
   a Synaptics touchpad, you could also try to uninstall that driver.
2. **Missing driver**
   There are several possibilities here. The first is to install the Asus drivers
   from [Asus Support](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/117/0/6/uMukvgmJcudOMl9w/45/). Be very careful, especially with the BIOS update.
   The second is to use a driver-update product and see if it finds a new keyboard
   driver (do not install new drivers for devices that work).
   A couple of such utilities are [Driver Easy](https://www.drivereasy.com/) and [Driver Talent](http://www.drivethelife.com/free-drivers-download-utility.html)
   (although personally I avoid such products).
3. **Verify your keyboard language**
   Some users report having their keyboard language changed to another incompatible
   variant. Verify it in Control Panel / Language.
4. **Turn Off Filter Keys**
   Click Start / Settings / Ease of access, then Keyboard in the left pane.
   Turn off Filter Keys in the right pane and reboot.
5. **Use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut**
   Some Asus users report that hitting this magical key-combination fixes
   non-functional keys. Sounds weird but is worth trying.
   Other users report similarly for the combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd> and
   the key that has a lock icon with `fn` written inside.
6. **Workarounds**
   If nothing works, you could try as workaround using a USB external keyboard,
   or even doing a clean install of Windows 10 (download first all Asus drivers
   from my above link and take an image backup of the disk with a product
   such as [AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) and create its restore
   boot CD or USB).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would run BIOS and tried if these keys works. (e.g. setting power-on password - but remember the password or discard changes while exiting BIOS!)

If they don't work I would try this solution, where is made more electronic isolation between cable and mother board.
https://defuse.ca/asuskeyboarddefect.htm

I would highly recommend to Do this only while your laptop is not connected to charger and battery is pulled out. And your laptop is not under warranty anymore.
The idea is removing keyboard (you should find this in detailed manual or even youtube) still connected to motherboard and putting piece of paper (or something common what will not cause damage to motherboard by pollution) between cable and mother board (not between cable itself). The thing is motherboard could possibly emit electromagnetic fields which disturb/block stream of informations in cable.
Then put it together and try.

This could not be the case, but some cleaning combined with this step could maybe help.

Comment: the keys are working in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other things that are mentioned here, I would first try draining any power from the laptop. Take the battery out and press/hold the power button a few times to make sure there is no power left in the laptop itself.

Next if the keyboard is still working in only BIOS and not OS, try using a Windows 10 repair disk to not only see if your keyboard works there, but attempt to run a repair that could solve the problem.

Let me know if these steps still don't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To see if it is a hardware keyboard issue, you should go to the [Start] menu, page down to the [Windows ease of access] item, launch the [On-screen keyboard] and see if it has the same issues that your physical keyboard does.

Also, you might want to check all of the hotkeys that are in use on your system to make sure that an app hasn't hijacked some of your normal keys.

- Example: The latest Skype update added Shift-A as a hotkey.  That makes it really hard to type a capital A.  [grin]

NirSoft has a no-install utility that will show you all hotkeys that are registered on your computer:

- HotKeysList v1.00
- http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hot_keys_list.html

Answer (score 1):

If it is using the windows 10 generic keyboard drivers: Your keyboard is defective.

I bet it is shorting the signals for some function keys (like play, pause, volume, etc) when you press those keys. Which BIOS and windows7 in safemode might ignore so they end up processing the lower ones.

If you have access to linux, try to run the `xev` utility. I have no idea what is the equivalent on windows. It will show you the keycodes arriving from the keyboard. I bet it will show weird values together with those keys you mention.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you keyboard layout is set to EN-US, this can be done from Control Panel. It's also possible that you've enabled NumLock feature accidentally, try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>NumLk</kbd> keyboard shortcut to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a drivers problem. Please reinstall the [ATKPackage (For Windows 10 Upgrade)](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/117/0/6/uMukvgmJcudOMl9w/45/) for the Asus x55c

Answer (score 0):

Well. I replaced the keyboard as it was broken.