# keys cause web page to scroll up and other problems

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, scrolling

This only started happening recently. Whenever I press ctrl, f2, f8, f9 and some other keys (not at the same time, I mean when I just press 1 of them), the web page I'm on scrolls up to the top and prevents me from scrolling down. When I'm on the desktop menu, the app shortcut that's located in the top left gets highlighted and stays highlighted, preventing me from opening any other apps because double clicking just opens the highlighted app. On youtube the video I'm watching starts skipping a lot. The problem stops if I press backspace or if I refresh, but it starts again whenever I press the keys I mentioned above. Anyone know what's wrong and how I can fix it? Preferably without any money being spent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can answer your question, but it could be helpful of your issue.

Try to reset the keyboard.

1. Open `Device Manager` by start or `win` + `X`
2. Scroll down to find `Keyboard` and expand it.
3. Select the keyboard you have
4. Click `uninstall`
5. Then **Click the Search for updates** button to prompt the keyboard to reappear in Device Manager.
6. Select the keyboard again. Click the keyboard's name.
7. Then click the **Update drivers** button at the top of the window.
8. Click `Search automatically for updated driver software`.
9. Allow the newest drivers to install. If there are any drivers available for your keyboard they will install automatically.
10. Restart your computer.

Hope this can help you.