# Keyboard interruption

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've run into a strange issue on Windows 10, and hoping someone could recommend a way to track it down.

This seems to happen at random and has been increasing over time.

The numbers along the top of the keyboard stop responding, just 1 to 0 to all application, can't type those at all. Some things I've noticed while this happens is when hitting those buttons, the monitor with the active window flashes. It flashes a transparent window (like an Aero window) with rounded corners strangely, behind all the open windows, for a second.

I've tried closing all my running applications in case it was one of them (I'm a developer, so there are usually tools running), but that didn't fix it. I tried changing keyboards even though it seems like a software issue, but that didn't fix it.

I did some experimenting the last couple times it happened and I found out just grabbing a window by the title bar and moving it allow the flashing to move to different monitors but then would stop. I replicated it again, and just moving a window cause everything to go back to normal.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered something like this before, or know of any applications I could use to try and monitor applications using keyboard input to try and catch the offending one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the initial Windows 10 Repair Procedure. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .  Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW , restart and test.  Also consider updating your computer drivers: BIOS, Video and remaining drivers. Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update program to do this.

Comment: I assume you've tested for malware infections...?

Comment: All drivers are up to date, and no malware. I did a fresh install of windows a couple weeks ago. The last time it happened I just had a couple applications running (VS2019, Chrome, and Discord). I keep an eye on running applications / background services for anything I don't recognize.

Comment: How old is your computer? An unstable USB power supply might create this kind of issue. Did you try a wireless keyboard?

Comment: Use Process Explorer (Microsoft SysInternals) to help you with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)