# Windows 10 Pressing Del key returns a dot

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

When I press <kbd>DEL</kbd> On windows 10, it does not erases the preceding character. It returns a dot (.). But in Windows 7 it correctly erased character.

Is this is a bug and is there any way to recover from it?

Comment: Sounds like different keyboard layouts.  This most definitely is not a bug

Comment: My locale is en-US and I also use Bangla keyboard software and layout not different.

Comment: You make no mention of using keyboard software in your question.

Comment: But I most times use English layout and the problem is there.

Comment: The use of third-party keyboard software is important.  I guarantee you this has something to do which keyboard layouts you have installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the Numeric Keypad `./del` key. Does it function properly if you toggle Numlock?

If it's the dedicated `delete` key, it sounds like it was remapped to send the Numeric Keypad `./del`.

Barring 3rd-party software, the built-in way to remap is via the registry key:
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'` 
and a REG_BINARY value named `ScanCode Map`:
[image]

If that value doesn't exist, please provide more detail.

Determine what scancode the key is sending with:
[Keyboard Test Utility](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Keyboard-Test-Utility.shtml)